# Understanding wildcards in Java generics

Tags: java, generics

I'm not sure why the last statement in the following code is illegal. `Integer` should be a subtype of `?`, so why can't I assign it to `b`?

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
a.add("foo");

// b is a List of anything
List<?> b = a;

// retrieve the first element
Object c = b.get(0);
// This is legal, because we can guarantee
// that the return type "?" is a subtype of Object

// Add an Integer to b.
b.add(new Integer (1));
```

Comment: I don't want to put this as an answer because I could be wrong, but doesn't declaring a `List<?>` have it infer the type on it when assigned? Creating a more vague list `List b` would imply type `Object`. Why get more technical with the `<?>` when its unnecessary. Again, I could be *extremely* wrong so someone could help with my ignorance as well.

Comment: No, that's not what ? means. It's just a wildcard which means "some unknown type".

Comment: Let me flip this around: why would you *want* the last line to compile? You are trying to add an `Integer` to `List<String>`. *That's bad!*

Comment: I've updated the question title, because it's not about covariance.

Comment: `List<?>` is similar to `List<? extends Object>`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The point is that `b` refers to a list of *some* type, but the compiler doesn't know what the type is, so it doesn't *know* whether or not it's valid to add an `Integer` to it. And a good thing too, given your example - you'd be adding an `Integer` to an object initially created to hold a list of strings. Sure, that information is lost at execution time in Java - but the compiler tries to keep you as safe as it can.

See the [Java generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) for a *lot* more information.

Comment: So concluding from this, when I declare something like List<?> list = new ArrayList<?>(), I can't add any object to the list because I can't guarantee that it is a subtype of ?

Comment: So what is the advantage of ?

Comment: @Roflcoptr: The tutorial gives an example (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html).

Comment: Thanks @OliCharlesworth and Jon Skeet, now I finally understand it.

Answer (score 3):

`Integer` is not a subtype of `?` (necessarily).  `?` is a wildcard; you should interpret it as meaning "unknown".

So a `List<?>` is not the same as a `List<Object>`.  You **can** add anything you like to a `List<Object>`.

Comment: I still don't understand it. if ? is anything why can't i add any object i like, for example Integer'

Comment: @Roflcoptr: `List<?>` is not the same as `List<Object>`.  You can add anything you like to a `List<Object>`.  You should interpret the `?` as meaning "unknown".

Comment: @Roflcoptr - `?` doesn't mean "anything"; it means "something unspecified".

Answer (score 2):

The reference "b" is declared as a List, that is, a "List of something I don't know yet".
You can assign pretty much any implementation to this reference, like a List. This is why it is forbidden to add anything to the lists through this reference.

Answer (score 1):

It's because we cannot guarantee that Integer is a subtype of the parameter type "?".

Look this:

```
Object c = b.get(0);
```

This is valid, as ? will always be an subtype from Object.

Answer (score 1):

A rough rule of thumb for collections and generics is the following:

- `Collection<Foo>` is a Collection from which you can get a Foo and to which you can add a Foo.
- `Collection<? extends Foo>` is a Collection from which you can get a Foo, **but you cannot add anything**.

Why is this so?  Because when you say `Collection<Foo>`, you're **promising** to the users of that reference that they can invoke an `add(Foo elem)` method on the object in question.  On the other hand, when you use the wildcard version, you're keeping the "real" parameter class a secret from the users of the reference—they know that any element they extract from the collection can be cast to Foo, but not whether they can add any Foo to it.

Why is this useful?  Because there are many, many, many cases where you will write methods that will want to iterate through a Collection whose elements are all Foos, but to which you never need to add any elements.  So like this:

```
public Foo findAFooThatILike(Collection<? extends Foo> foos);
```

Using the wildcard here means that the method will accept as its argument a `Collection<Foo>` and a collection of any subtype of Foo; e.g., if Bar is a subtype of Foo, the signature above means that you can pass a `Collection<Bar>` to the method.

If on the other hand, you'd written the signature like this:

```
public Foo findAFooThatILike(Collection<Foo> foos);
```

...then you would **not** be able to pass in a `Collection<Bar>` as an argument.  Why?  Because for something to be a `Collection<Foo>`, it needs to support an `add(Foo elem)` method, and a `Collection<Bar>` doesn't.

Note that these rules of thumb only apply to Collection interfaces and classes.  (Also note that `Collection<? extends Foo>` doesn't mean "read-only Collection of Foo"; many methods to remove elements from a collection can still work when you don't know the precise element type).

So, back to your original question: `List<?>` is the same as `List<? extends Object>`.  It's a list from which you can get references to Object instances, but you cannot safely add anything.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short summary of what you can and cannot do with generics:

```
    List<? extends Number> listOfAnyNumbers = null;
    List<Number> listOfNumbers = null;
    List<Integer> listOfIntegers = null;
    listOfIntegers = listOfNumbers;     // Error - because listOfNumbers may contain non-integers
    listOfNumbers = listOfIntegers;     // Error - because to a listOfNumbers you can add any Number, while to listOfIntegers you cannot.
    listOfIntegers = listOfAnyNumbers;  // Error - because listOfAnyNumbers may contain non-integers  
    listOfAnyNumbers = listOfIntegers;  // OK    - because listOfIntegers is a list of ?, where ? extends Number.
    listOfNumbers = listOfAnyNumbers;   // Error - because listOfAnyNumbers may actually be List<Float>, to which you cannot add any Number. 
    listOfAnyNumbers = listOfNumbers;   // OK    - because listOfNumbers is a list of ?, where ? extends Number.
```

Answer (score 0):

List<?> means a list typed to an unknown type.This could be a List of Integer, String or XYZ class.

Since you don't know what type of list is typed to, you can only read from the collection, and you can only treat the Objects read as being Object instance.

Please go for super wildcard boundary if you want to insert elements in the wildcard generic collection.