# Adding object to a list of supertypes with wildcards

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, subtype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Understanding wildcards in Java generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481052/understanding-wildcards-in-java-generics)

I have a class Car which is extended by Chevrolet. Then you can see quite normal piece of code:

`List<? extends Chevrolet> extededChevrolets = new ArrayList<>();

 List<? extends Car>  extendedCars = extededChevrolets;`

Now why can't I perform operation like:

`extendedCars.add(new Chevrolet());`

Comment: Maybe this answer on another question can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5408550/1091424

Answer (score -2):

it may be because you spelled extendedChevrolets wrong when you made the List! you spelled it extededChevrolets, not extendedChevrolets! 
Hope this helps!

Comment: No man, it's definitely not this. I can recognise compilation error.